# Scheduling Threads and Synchronized Methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I've created a class called TSchedule that implements Runnable and extends Thread, and will be used to sequence a handful of Threads (t1, t2, ..., t8).

Each instance of TSchedule is passed in a Thread name, an arrival time (sleep time), a list of dependencies (a TSchedule array), and a flag).

After each thread is done executing the run() method, the respective thread is supposed to print out "Thread.getName() is terminating", however, I can't seem  to get all of the threads to print that out.

```
public class TSchedule extends Thread implements Runnable {
       private TSchedule[] dependencies;
       private int sleepTime;
           private boolean done;

    public TSchedule (String name, int sleep, TSchedule[] dependencies, boolean done) {
        super(name); 
        sleepTime = sleep; 
        this.dependencies = dependencies;
        this.done = done;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(sleepTime); 
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.println(getName() + " arrived at time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        checkDependencies(dependencies);
        System.err.println(getName() + " is terminating");
    }

    public synchronized void checkDependencies(TSchedule[] dependencies) {
        if(dependencies != null)
            for(int i = 0; i < dependencies.length; i++) {
                if(dependencies[i].done != true) {
                    System.out.println(getName() + " waiting on " + dependencies[i].getName() 
                            + " time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        done = true;
        notify();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TSchedule t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8;

        t1 = new TSchedule("t1", 4, null, false);
        t2 = new TSchedule("t2", 6, null, false);
        t3 = new TSchedule("t3", 7, null, false);
        t4 = new TSchedule("t4", 2, new TSchedule[] {t1, t2}, false);
        t5 = new TSchedule("t5", 3, new TSchedule[] {t3}, false);
        t6 = new TSchedule("t6", 1, new TSchedule[] {t3, t4}, false);
        t7 = new TSchedule("t7", 8, new TSchedule[] {t4}, false);
        t8 = new TSchedule("t8", 5, new TSchedule[] {t6}, false);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();
        t6.start();
        t7.start();
        t8.start();
    }
 }
```

Here is the output I am receiving:

```
t4 arrived at time 1398211394620
t6 arrived at time 1398211394620
t5 arrived at time 1398211394621
t4 waiting on t1 time 1398211394620
t5 waiting on t3 time 1398211394621
t6 waiting on t3 time 1398211394621
t1 arrived at time 1398211394622
t1 is terminating
t8 arrived at time 1398211394624
t8 waiting on t6 time 1398211394624
t2 arrived at time 1398211394624
t2 is terminating
t3 arrived at time 1398211394625
t3 is terminating
t7 arrived at time 1398211394627
t7 waiting on t4 time 1398211394627
```

Comment: What does `wait()` do?

Comment: wait() puts the current Thread in a waiting state, releasing the lock it has on the TSchedule object, which allows other Thread instances to enter checkDependencies().

Comment: Why implement runnable and extend thread in the same class!

Comment: So I can give a name to each Thread instance by calling super("name")

Comment: As @MingtaoZhang said, if the class extends Thread, it does not need to implement Runnable again.

Comment: So if I only implement Runnable, how can I give each Thread a unique name (i.e t1, t2, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `wait` and `notify` calls should be made on different objects.

Let's make a dry run with `t4` which depends on `t1` and `t2` and is not terminating.

```
t4 arrived at time 1398211394620
t1 arrived at time 1398211394622
t1 is terminating
t2 arrived at time 1398211394624
t2 is terminating
```

Because `t4` runs first, it will see that `t1` has not finished and will call `wait()` which is a short way of calling `this.wait()`, i.e. `t4.wait()`

Now `t1` runs and because it does not have any dependencies it will go directly to `notify()`. The problem is that is actually calling `this.notify()` which in turn is `t1.notify()`, and it should be calling `t4.notify()` instead. Same thing with `t2`.

Therefore, no one wakes `t4` up, and it stays there, waiting for someone to tell him to continue.

Check the documentation for `wait` and `notify`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html and you will see that you need to make the calls on the same lock object to get the behaviour you are expecting.

One way to solve your problem is to surround your `if` block with a `synchronized` block and change your `wait()` call:

```
synchronized (dependencies[i]) {
    if (dependencies[i].done != true) {
        ...
        dependencies[i].wait();
        ...
    }
}
done = true;
notify();
```

So each TSchedule wait for its dependencies to finish and then it notifies about itself.

Comment: How would I be able to notify() then?

Comment: Could you please explain why each dependency is calling wait() and notify()? Thank you.

Comment: With my solution, the parents are waiting for their dependencies explicitly. At the same time, each TSchedule that do not have dependencies, will end normally and notify. This notifications will be received by the parent that are explicitly waiting, and so on. Follow the dry run to help you understand the concept.

Comment: I've edited my solution to include the notify at the end to make it clearer.